# Apply function to every pair of columns in two matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I'd like to apply a function to every pair of column vectors in matrices `A` and `B`. I know there must be an efficient (non `for`) way of doing this, but I can't figure it out. The function will output a scalar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
na = size(A,1);
nb = size(B,1);
newvector = bsxfun(@(j,k)(func(A(j,:),B(k,:))),1:na,(1:nb)');
```

`bsxfun` performs singleton expansion on 1:na and (1:nb)'. The end result, in this case, is that func will be applied to every pair of column vectors drawn from A and B.

Note that bsxfun can be tricky: it can require that the applied function support singleton expansion itself. In this case it will work to do the job you want.

Comment: I tried the same where my func is dot product but it gave me error saying arguments of dot must be of same size... Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: @Bob is it possible that you need to call by column and not by row: `bsxfun( @(j,k) func(A(:,j),A(:,k)), 1:na, (1:nb)' )` works?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean pairwise? So in a for-loop the function will work as `scalar_val = func(A(i),B(i))`?

If `A` and `B` have the same size you can apply [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) function:

```
newvector = arrayfun(@(x) func(A(x),B(x)), 1:numel(A));
```

**UPDATE**:

According your comment you need to run all combinations of A and B as `scalar_val = func(A(i), B(j))`. This is a little more complicated and for large vectors can fill the memory quickly.

If your function is one of standard you can try using [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
out = bsxfun(@plus, A, B');
```

Another way is to use [MESHGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) and ARRAYFUN:

```
[Am, Bm] = meshgrid(A,B);
out = arrayfun(@(x) func(Am(x),Bm(x)), 1:numel(Am));
out = reshape(out, numel(A), numel(B));
```

I believe it should work, but I don't have time to test it now.

Comment: In the for loop it should be `scalar_val = func(A(i), B(j))`