# Apply a function to all column pairs between two matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab function `z = foo(x, y)` that takes two column vector as inputs and output a scalar. Now I would like to apply this function to two matrices A(dimension n * d1) and B (dimension n * d2) and generate a d1 * d2 matrix, such that `output(i, j) = foo( A(:, i), B(:, j) )`. It should basically resemble the behavior of applying the `corr` function to two matrices.

I tried the solutions in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813554/apply-function-to-every-pair-of-columns-in-two-matrices-in-matlab), but the encounter the same problem in the first answer, and the `meshgrid` step in second solution is way too slow.

Any suggestions? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Can your `foo` function accept a matrices or do you need to pass each column one by one?

Comment: It only accepts two column vectors.

Comment: So then in that case won't you have to loop no matter what? Have you tested passing in two *m*-by-*1*-by-*n* matrices and seeing if it works? It might make sense for you to rework your function so that it can accept an input like this

Comment: @sean_xia why does the `bsxfun` solution not working for you? what is the problem you encountered? `bsxfun( @(ii,jj) foo(A(:,ii),A(:,jj)), (1:d1)', 1:d2)` not working?

Comment: @Shai Here is what I have tried. First setting up two test matrices `n = 1000; d1 = 30; d2 = 100; A = randn(n, d1); B = randn(n, d2)`. Then applying your code: `bsxfun( @(ii,jj) dot(A(:,ii),A(:,jj)), (1:d1)', 1:d2)` gives me error "A and B must be same size". When using my function: `bsxfun( @(ii,jj) foo(A(:,ii),A(:,jj)), (1:d1)', 1:d2)`, the error message is "Error using bsxfun. Invalid output dimensions".

Comment: @Dan That function is from a collaborator and it takes two matrices of same dimensions as inputs. I just figured that in my case all pairwise callings of `foo` are completed independent, so I'd like to avoid writing for-loops if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If `foo` accepts a matrix then:

```
%Find dimensions
dA = size(A,2);
dB = size(B,2);


%Generate a list of all possible column pairs for the two matrices
indA = ceil((1:dA*dB)/dA);
indB = mod(0:dA*dB, dB)+1;

X = A(:, indA);
Y = B(:, indB);

z = foo(X,Y)
```

then you'll probably be able to reshape `z` to what you want

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. Unfortunately, my dmax is on the order of thousands, so the `ind = dec2bin(0:2^dmax, dmax)` step give me "Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded".

Comment: So then you're dealing with over one billion pairs... far far more if you're running 64 bit Matlab on 64 bit OS. Perhaps you should be looping in pages? i.e. break your matrices down into smaller matrices and run code like mine above on each of the smaller bits, saving as you go along?

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me, @Dan. A has 30 columns, and B has 3000 columns. So there are 90,000 pairs. The `corr` function fro MATLAB takes less than 1 second to compute these 90,000 correlation coefficients.